# Как сделать медленное появление картинки из невидимости?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинка, надо, чтобы она медленно из невидимой становилось видимой. По логике, задача-то элементарная, но голова никак не сообразит(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я люблю так делать: `<div class="picture"></div>`

```
.picture { 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
  animation-duration: 1s; 
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; 
  animation-name: fadeIn;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% {opacity: 0;} 
    100% {opacity: 1;} 
} 
@keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% {opacity: 0;} 
    100% {opacity: 1;} 
}
```